# Telegram Bot sendPhoto via node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

i'm using this function for sending photo via node.js but that not work.
**telegram-bot-api**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegram-bot-api

```
var telegram = require('telegram-bot-api');

var api = new telegram({
    token: '<PUT YOUR TOKEN HERE>',
});

api.sendPhoto({
    chat_id: <YOUR CHAT ID>,
    caption: 'This is my test image',

    // you can also send file_id here as string (as described in telegram bot api documentation)
    photo: '/path/to/file/test.jpg'
})
.then(function(data)
{
    console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null));
});
```

but i have this error

```
 fn = function () { throw arg; };
                           ^
StatusCodeError: 403 - [object Object]
```

Comment: Are you using any node package to implement telegram bot api? 
If you aren't using any telegram bot node packages, then the sendPhoto function should include parameters like destination user ID along with photo url like sendPhoto(userId, photo_url)

Comment: i'm using telegram-bot-api moudules  

but i have this error    fn = function () { throw arg; };
                           ^
StatusCodeError: 403 - [object Object]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. Looks like you are using the chat ID of your own bot to send the photo which is invalid. Thus, you are getting 403 forbidden error(refer [telegram bot errors api](https://core.telegram.org/api/errors))

To use sendPhoto function you will have to use the chat ID of the user not your bot's user. I have made few modifications to your code to make it clear for you. This code will get the user's chat Id from `message.chatid` variable.
Just replace your token in this code and mention your **image url** and try it.

PS: Send any message to this bot and it will send a photo in response.

```
var telegram = require('telegram-bot-api');

var api = new telegram({
    token: 'Your BOT token',
    updates: {
                enabled: true,
                get_interval: 1000
             }
});
api.on('message', function(message)
{
    var chat_id = message.chat.id;
        console.log("This is the user's chat id"+chat_id);

api.sendPhoto({
    chat_id : message.chat.id,
    caption: 'This is my test image',
    photo: 'image.jpeg'//replace your image url here
})
.then(function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

Comment: let me know if this has helped you @Sedric Heidarizarei

Comment: Am Glad that it help you @sedric-heidarizarei

Answer (score 1):

as described in telegram bot [api documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile) you can send a file with two different ways: 

**1- sending image by image url :**
   so you should set photo parameter to an image url, something like below

```js
api.sendPhoto({
    chat_id: <YOUR CHAT ID>,
    caption: 'image sent by uploading from url',

    // first you upload image on a url and send url as a parameter
    photo: 'https://whatbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Download-Telegram-App-For-PC-Laptop-Windows-XP-7-8-MAC-OS.png'
})
.then(function(data)
{
    console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null));
});
```

**2- sending image by file_id**

each file that upload in telegram server have an id that you can use this id to avoid reuploading the image to telegram server so in api you should pass the file_id of an image file, something like below :

```js
    api.sendPhoto({
        chat_id: <YOUR CHAT ID>,
        caption: 'the image sent by file_id',

        // it is a file_id that you get when someone upload an image to 
        photo: 'AgADBAADZbo1G14XZAfdtXnWB5anFpRbYRkABMRWzQmdc4EQbPcCAAEC'
    })
    .then(function(data)
    {
        console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null));
    });
```

Comment: why i need a chat id?  i will want to send a photo to my bot when shomeone Clicked on `/start` button