# How to send local photo in telegram bot for java

Tags: java, automated-tests, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a task: 
Need sending a photo with my local folder in telegram bot.

Precondition:

I use this library https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots

In Pom file:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.rubenlagus</groupId>
        <artifactId>TelegramBots</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

How to create Send Method?

I tried to do so:

```
public void sendInTelegram() {
    try {
        TelegramLongPollingBot telegramLongPollingBot = new TelegramLongPollingBot() {
            @Override
            public String getBotToken() {
                return "My_Token";
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
                try {
                    SendPhoto message = new SendPhoto().setPhoto("SomeText", new FileInputStream(new File("/root/index.png")));
                    this.sendPhoto(message);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String getBotUsername() {
                return "my_bot";
            }
        };
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Send in Telegram fail");
        Assert.fail("Send in Telegram fail");
    }
```

but his.sendPhoto(message); sendPhoto is unresolved 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWb0q.png)

Please tell me what is not enough that I could send a photo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [send photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776000/telegram-bot-sendphoto-via-node-js)

Comment: I'm asking a Java implementation and not Node.js

Answer (score 2):

Use `execute`, not `sendPhoto`:

```
SendPhoto message = new SendPhoto().setPhoto("SomeText", new FileInputStream(new File("/root/index.png")));
this.execute(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set chatID also:

```
try {
     SendPhoto sendPhoto = new SendPhoto()
           .setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId())
           .setPhoto("Photo", new FileInputStream(new File("/root/index.png")));
     execute(sendPhoto);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this working example:

```
public void sendPhotoMessage(long chatId, UserContent content) {

        String caption = getCaption(content);

        SendPhoto sendPhoto = SendPhoto.builder()
            .chatId(chatId)
            .photo(new InputFile(new File(content.getMediaUrl())))
            .caption(caption)
            .parseMode(ParseMode.HTML)
            .build();

        try {
            chronologyBot.execute(sendPhoto);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            log.error("Can't send photo message", e);
        }
    }
```

Also for case when we want to send multiple photos in one message we can use SendMediaGroup. Question and examples here: [Send multiple images with MediaGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63635009/send-multiple-images-with-mediagroup/75267895#75267895)